# d3 setting minimum height for stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart using d3.js but I am having a problem.
The problem is when there is a bar with the value of 1 in a 10,000 height Y axis, the bar has 0px height and it doesn't appear on the chart.

Example of data that causes the problem:
`[{green: 1, yellow: 9400, white: 999999}]`

The "green" bar will be so small, it's like it doesn't exist.

Here's the **relevant** code:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 1),
    y = d3.scale.linear()
        .rangeRound([height + 2, margin.top]);

var d3Elm = d3.select(element[0]);

var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(data);

x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function(d){
    return d3StackedBarCtrl.labelEllipsis(d.displayName, 10);
}));

y.domain([0,
    d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1],
        function (d) {
            return d.y0 + d.y;
        })
    ]).nice();

var layer = svg.selectAll('.stack')
    .data(dataStackLayout)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'stack');

layer.selectAll('rect')
    .data(function(d){
        return d;
    })
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d){
        return x(d.displayName);
    })
    .attr('y', function(d){
        return y(d.y + d.y0);
    })
    .attr('width', 24)
    .attr('height', function(d){
        return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
    })
    .attr('class', 'rect');
```

How can I set a minimum height for bars **and** have the other bars reduce their height on the account of extended bars?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else, what you're doing is *lying with data*. If green is several orders of magnitude smaller than white, let it be, and explain that for your readers somewhere in the chart. But I understand that you just want make the respective rectangle visible.

There are two ways of doing that, changing the matrix of the stacked data or changing the rectangles themselves. As you just want to make the bar barely visible, I'd go with the second option, that doesn't involve changing the data (aka *lying*!), creating a rule that sets a minimum height for the bar. As this bar will overlap just a little bit the next bar we **won't** need to change the other bars values (contrary to your request); besides that, it deals with pixels, not with data.

The rule can be something as simple as this:

```
.attr("height", function(d) { 
    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y) < 2 ? 2 : y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); 
})
```

Which says: "check for the computed height. Is it less than 2 pixels? If yes, set the height for 2 pixels. If not, set the height for the computed one".

Check this demo (this code is not mine, I just found it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xavipolo/q5q6331p/). I made "oranges" have a small value in 2007. Still, the respective bar has a minimum height of 4 pixels:

```js
// Setup svg using Bostock's margin convention

var margin = {top: 20, right: 160, bottom: 35, left: 30};

var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

var data = [
  { year: "2006", redDelicious: "100", mcintosh: "150", oranges: "90", pears: "60" },
  { year: "2007", redDelicious: "120", mcintosh: "180", oranges: "1", pears: "40" },
  { year: "2008", redDelicious: "050", mcintosh: "200", oranges: "80", pears: "20" },
  { year: "2009", redDelicious: "010", mcintosh: "150", oranges: "50", pears: "40" },
  { year: "2010", redDelicious: "020", mcintosh: "100", oranges: "40", pears: "20" },
  { year: "2011", redDelicious: "030", mcintosh: "120", oranges: "60", pears: "30" },
  { year: "2012", redDelicious: "040", mcintosh: "150", oranges: "80", pears: "10" },
  { year: "2013", redDelicious: "060", mcintosh: "110", oranges: "90", pears: "40" },
  { year: "2014", redDelicious: "100", mcintosh: "130", oranges: "90", pears: "50" },
  { year: "2015", redDelicious: "160", mcintosh: "190", oranges: "60", pears: "90" },
  { year: "2016", redDelicious: "190", mcintosh: "170", oranges: "50", pears: "70" },
];

var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;


// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"].map(function(fruit) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {x: parse(d.year), y: +d[fruit]};
  });
}));


// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];


// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat( function(d) { return d } );

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y) < 4 ? 4 : y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });


// Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")"; });
 
legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {return colors.slice().reverse()[i];});
 
legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) { 
    switch (i) {
      case 0: return "Anjou pears";
      case 1: return "Naval oranges";
      case 2: return "McIntosh apples";
      case 3: return "Red Delicious apples";
    }
  });


// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");
    
tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried that. It's not a good solution because if you have more than one rectangle that needs to be "extended" visibly, then they all overlap each other so only one is visible. Therefor, the Y attribute also needs to change according to other rectangles position.

Comment: @MatanReuven That's because of the "lying with data". If you have data saying one thing, and want visuals to say another then you have to craft that visual display. If you dodgy one pixel size then you have to dodgy them all... but how and by how much? I believe there is a reason no one answers these questions, the best response I've seen is "Implement a zoom feature". Otherwise perhaps a logarithmic scale can help to some extent.